# Negative lookahead for "select filenames whithout extansion"

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to add "php" to all urls in `href="xxx"`, that don't end with "php".
I use negetive lookahead `(?!php)`:

```
find = r'href="(.+?)(?!php)"'
replace =  r'href="\1.php"'
re.sub(find, replace, 'href="url"')
re.sub(find, replace, 'href="url.php"')
```

both add extension:

```
href="url.php"
href="url.php.php"
```

Why negative lookahead doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does work:

```
In [49]: re.sub(r'href="([^"]*?)([.]php)?"', r'href="\1.php"', 'href="url.php"')
Out[49]: 'href="url.php"'

In [50]: re.sub(r'href="([^"]*?)([.]php)?"', r'href="\1.php"', 'href="url"')
Out[50]: 'href="url.php"'
```

The reason your original regex `(.+?)(?!php)` doesn't quite work is that it matches `url.php` as follows:

- `(.+?)` matches `url.php`;
- at this point the negative lookahead is satisfied since the next character is a double quote.

In other words, `.+?` consumes the entire filename including the extension, making the lookahead a no-op.

Comment: yep, it works. Btw, I managed to work negetive lookahead: `find = 'href="([^"]*?)(?!php)([^"]{3})"'`, `replace =  r'href="\1\2.php"'`. But it is ugly.

Comment: @Qiao: That new lookahead version is a bit broken. Consider what it does to `href="q"`.

Comment: so it is not possible to use easy lookahead pattern for this case, right?

Comment: @Qiao: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. I don't know. Why the fixation on lookahead, when a straightforward non-lookahead regex does the job?

Comment: @ NPE, isn't this bulletproof: `href="([^"]+?)(?<!php)"`? Yep, it works, but lookahead and stuff is just beautiful )

Comment: @Qiao: This might work. The problem with lookahead/behind is that they often behave in subtle ways and can be hard to get right. I tend to use them only when nothing else works.

Comment: @ NPE, I agree, they are confusing. But they are so beautiful )

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead means the regexp tries to match next pattern, but does not consume the pattern. Your pattern `"(.+?)(?!php)"` matches 1 or more number of any characters until it meets `"`, then tries to match next pattern, which is `php`. This lookahead will always fail, because the next character is `"`, and since this is a NEGATIVE lookahead, the whole pattern will succeed.

What you need is the negative lookbehind, (`(?<!PATTERN)`) which will try to match the pattern AFTER the character is consumed. When it meets `"`, lookbehind pattern tries to match last 3 characters against pattern `php`.

In short, please try again with below pattern

```
find = 'href="(.+?)(?<!php)"'
```

Comment: It messes this: `href="url.php" someattr="xxx"'` -> `href="url.php" someattr=.php"xxx"`